# How to change the look of a button in Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, interface

i've searched a bit and i couldn't seem to find this question asked specifically for Java.  I'm trying to change the `Look and Feel of a JButton` and the looks of other elements like `JTextFields` and `JComboBox`.  To make my question clearer, i'm not trying to change the color or the shape of my button.  I want to the change the "interface", i guess that's a good way to put it.  Java has a default "`LaF`" for `JButtons` and other elements, how do i change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

Next time google your question first.